# Bloom filter implementation using a BitArray

Tags: ruby, bloom-filter

I am following the Wikipedia definition of the Bloom filter. My implementation uses the `BitArray` I created [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67364/bit-array-in-ruby-using-integer-as-a-storage). [Here](https://github.com/igrigorik/bloomfilter-rb/blob/master/examples/pure-ruby-bf.rb) is an alternative implementation by Ilya Grigorik.

```
# n = Number of items in the filter
# p = Probability of false positives, float between 0 and 1 or a number indicating 1-in-p
# m = Number of bits in the filter
# k = Number of hash functions

require_relative '../bitarray/bit_array'
require 'digest'

class BloomFilter

  def initialize k: 1, m: 10
    @k = k
    @m = m
    @n = 0
    @b = BitArray.new
  end

  # Probability of a false positive based on formula in wikipedia
  def false_positive_rate
    fp_rate = (1-(1-1/@m.to_f)**(@k.to_f*@n.to_f))**@k.to_f
    p fp_rate
    fp_rate.round(2)
  end 

  def insert item
    @n += 1
    @k.times do |n|
      hash_val = Digest::MD5.hexdigest( item.to_s + n.to_s ).to_i(16)
      position = hash_val % @m
      @b.set position
    end  
    self
  end   

  def include? item
    @k.times do |n|
      hash_val = Digest::MD5.hexdigest( item.to_s + n.to_s ).to_i(16)
      position = hash_val % @m
      return @b.get(position) == 1
    end     
    return false
  end  

end
```

The test:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require_relative 'bloom_filter'

class BloomFilterTest < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase

  # Verified probability formula and tests from http://hur.st/bloomfilter?n=1&p=0.01
  def test_stats
    assert_equal 0.01, BloomFilter.new(k: 7, m: 10).insert("a").false_positive_rate
    b = BloomFilter.new(k: 2, m: 29)
    10.times { |n| b.insert(n) }
    assert_equal 0.25, b.false_positive_rate
  end 

  def test_include
    b = BloomFilter.new(k: 2, m: 100)
    b.insert "The Trumpet of the Swan"
    assert_equal true, b.include?("The Trumpet of the Swan")
    refute b.include?("E. B. White")   
  end  

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You're using `assert_equal` to compare something with `true` - which is exactly what the basic `assert` method already does. Just like you use `refute` to check that something's false, `assert` checks that something's true.
- You might want to check that \$k ≤ m\$. Doesn't really make sense otherwise. (Of course it doesn't *really* make sense for \$k\$ to *equal* \$m\$ either, as adding just 1 item would set every bit right away, but at least that's technically valid.)
- In this case, I'm OK with using single-letter variables like `k` and `m`, since that appears to be conventional enough, and they're hard to give simple, yet descriptive names. <strike>*However,* I'd also add copious comments to explain exactly what the heck they mean. I had to go to Wikipedia to find out.</strike> (Edit: Sorry, comments already there, just not by the `#initialize` method, where I expected them to be.)
- `p fp_rate` - don't leave print calls in final code (unless that code's purpose is to print, of course).
- Why does `#false_positive_rate` round its output? Rounding is a presentation concern; the rate just is what it is, decimals and all. I'm thinking you're maybe rounding so it passes your tests, but in that case you're writing your code backwards.
- **Your `#include?` method is broken**. It'll return (from the *method*; not just the block) at the *first* bit it checks - it won't check all of them. So if the first bit it checks is zero, you get `false` - which is correct! But if the first bit is 1, you immediate get `true` even though none of the other *k*-1 bits have been checked.
  This also means that your false positive rate is *at best*

  $$1 - (1 - \frac{1}{m})^n$$

  because \$k\$ is effectively always 1 when checking. But if \$k\$ is higher, then we'd be setting more bits than we're checking, so the bit array fills up faster.
  For instance, if \$k = 2\$ and \$m = 4\$ (extreme values; just for illustration), then the first item (call it \$A\$) we insert should set half of the bits in the bit array. That *should* (if my math is correct) give a false positive rate of ~19% after adding that one item: There's a 19% chance that another item, \$B\$, will match the same 2 bits. But if we only check 1 bit, then the false positive rate is essentially 50%, since half the bits in the array are set.

  Making only only minimal changes, you could do this:

  ```
  @k.times do |n|
    hash_val = Digest::MD5.hexdigest( item.to_s + n.to_s ).to_i(16)
    position = hash_val % @m
    return false if @b.get(position).zero?
  end     
  true
  ```

  Now, it'll only return if a bit is zero, otherwise it'll keep going.
- But **your hashing logic is flawed too**, I'm afraid. There's no guarantee that it'll return \$k\$ *unique* bit positions (for \$k > 1\$). It's *possible* (though unlikely) that you'll calculate \$k\$ MD5 hashes that are all cleanly divisible by (i.e. are multiples of) \$m\$. In that case, you'd just get the bit position zero \$k\$ number of times and end up setting a single bit. It's a similar situation to the one above, since again, the false positive rate rises.
  If, for example, \$k = 2\$ and \$m = 4\$ again, and we've added item \$A\$ which (correctly) set 2 bits, we should have that 19% false positive rate when checking \$B\$. But if the hash for \$B\$ works out so that it's just 1 bit instead of 2, then we're back to a 50% false positive rate since it's only that 1 bit that would have to match, rather than 2 separate bits.

  *Frankly, I don't know enough about creating robust hashing functions to offer a good solution to this. I'll continue and **I'll provide alternative code for different things, but it all includes this basic flaw** (except in the addendum at the end). The code I provide here won't fix that; it's there to illustrate other aspects of the code.*
- You've duplicated the logic for hashing items. Duplication is always bad, but this is a prime example of why: If the two pieces of code aren't exactly identical, the whole thing stops functioning. I'd extract the hashing logic into a separate, private method that returns an array of bit positions

  ```
   def item_bit_positions item
     @k.times.map do |n|
       hash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest("#{item}#{n}").to_i(16)
       hash % @m
     end
   end
  ```

  You'll note that I'm using string interpolation; IMO it's clearer than manually calling `to_s` and concatenating. The results the same, though, but that result may not be what you want (see below)
- Using MD5 and then discarding a bunch of stuff really feels like overkill. [Ruby already maintains a hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-hash) for anything that inherits from `Object` (i.e. everything). It's what's used to check for object equality, and it's hexadecimal number you see printed if you print an object that doesn't have a `#to_s` method.
  `#hash` is just a (signed) integer. You could do something like:

  ```
   def item_bit_positions item
     @k.times.map { |n| item.hash % (@m-n) }
   end
  ```

  (**Again**, this is just as flawed [edit: Actually, it's more flawed, see below] as your current implementation (it can return fewer than \$k\$ positions); it's just here to illustrate how `#hash` can be used.)

  The above does not require `digest`. It does however require that \$k ≤ m - 1\$, or you'll get a divide-by-zero error.

  Note, though, that unlike MD5 which will always produce the same output for a given input, `#hash` is simply a number generated at runtime, so it'll be different each time you run the code. This could make testing tricky, since you're also dealing with something that *can* produce false positives. (One solution to this might be to stub out `#hash` on the items you're inserting.)

  Using `#hash` also changes the behavior somewhat since it's now about object-wise equality - not *string-wise* equality. In your implementation, the string `"foo"` and the symbol `:foo` would be treated as one and the same, since both have the same string representation, and you're converting everything to a string to calculate the MD5 hash. But using `#hash` there's no such collision.
- You're using your `BitArray` class, but I'd be tempted to just re-roll some of the same logic here, since it doesn't take much, and the implementation can be more specific. You can do everything with integers and bitwise manipulation.

```
class BloomFilter
  # This reader is mostly here for test purposes,
  # which isn't too pretty, I'm afraid. At least
  # it's a pretty harmless addition
  attr_reader :bit_array

  # TODO: Explain what k and m mean!
  def initialize(k = 1, m = 10)
    k, m = k.to_i, m.to_i
    raise RangeError, "k must be smaller than m" if k >= m
    raise ArgumentError, "k and m must be positive integers" if k < 1
    @k = k
    @m = m
    @bit_array = 0
  end

  def insert(item)
    @bit_array |= digest(item)
    self
  end

  def include?(item)
    hash = digest(item)
    @bit_array & hash == hash
  end
  alias_method :member?, :include?

  private

  # WARNING: This method is flawed! See answer
  def digest(item)
    hash = item.hash
    @k.times.map do |n|
      bit = (hash % (@m-n))
      2**bit
    end.inject(&:|)
  end
end



gem 'minitest'
require 'minitest/autorun'

class BloomFilterTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_initialize_with_valid_args
    assert BloomFilter.new(1, 2)
  end

  def test_initialize_with_invalid_args
    assert_raises RangeError do
      BloomFilter.new(2, 2)
    end
  end

  def test_initialize_with_negative_args
    assert_raises ArgumentError do
      BloomFilter.new(-2, 2)
    end
  end

  def test_insert_uses_the_items_hash
    item = mock_item(123)
    instance = BloomFilter.new
    instance.insert(item)
    item.verify
  end

  def test_insert_changes_the_bit_array
    instance = BloomFilter.new
    previous = instance.bit_array
    instance.insert(Object.new)
    refute_equal previous, instance.bit_array
  end

  def test_include_uses_the_items_hash
    item = mock_item(123)
    instance = BloomFilter.new
    instance.include?(item)
    item.verify
  end

  def test_include_returns_true_for_member
    item = mock_item(123, 2)
    instance = BloomFilter.new
    instance.insert(item)
    assert instance.include?(item)
  end

  def test_include_returns_false_for_nonmember
    member = mock_item(123)
    non_member = mock_item(122)
    instance = BloomFilter.new(3, 10)
    instance.insert(member)
    refute instance.include?(non_member)
  end

  # An intentionally failing test
  def test_digest_always_sets_k_bits
    k = 3
    item = mock_item(720) # multiple of 10, 8 and 9
    instance = BloomFilter.new(k, 10)
    hash = instance.send(:digest, item) # testing private method
    assert_equal k, count_bits(hash), "Note: This test intentionally fails!"
  end

  # A helper method (mock object factory)
  def mock_item(hash, calls = 1)
    mock = Minitest::Mock.new
    calls.times { mock.expect(:hash, hash) }
    mock
  end

  def count_bits(number)
    count = 0
    until number == 0
      count += (number & 1)
      number = number >> 1
    end
    count
  end
end
```

---

A thing I've noticed in you past few questions: You're writing tests which is great, but you're writing the barest minimum of tests. For instance, you're not testing `#insert` at all, and your test for `#include?` doesn't include an edge case as the one mentioned above where 2 items shared the same first bit - but not all of them.

Basically, you should have a higher test-to-code ratio. It's not uncommon to have way more test code than implementation code; in fact that's something to aim for.

---

**Addendum:** This is an interesting topic, actually. Not usually my cup of tea (I suck at theoretical stuff like this), but I got [nerd sniped](http://xkcd.com/356/).

I've also realized that my hash implementation is even *more* flawed than I thought: Even if it manages to set \$k\$ bits (which isn't guaranteed), their distribution isn't random. Since I'm using modulo `@m - n`, only the first iteration has a chance of setting the highest bit. Boo, me, boo.

Anyway, as I said, I don't know of a way to construct a hash function that will always set exactly \$k\$ bits with random distribution, and I'm not smart enough to work one out - but I can think of a hack.

If \$m\$ is simply defined to be some multiple of \$k\$, then we can do something like this:

If we say that \$k = 4\$ and our multiplier \$f = 8\$ (just as an example), then \$m = k \cdot f = 32\$. So we have an array that's 32 bits long, *or* - to put it another way - we have 4 arrays that are each 8 bits long.

We can then do something like this (using `#hash` for simplicity):

```
mask = 0
k.times do |n|
  hash = calc_hash(n, item) # calculate a big 'ol hash (assume this method exists)
  mask = mask << f          # shift our current mask f places
  mask |= 2**(hash % f)     # set a bit somewhere in the lower f places
end
```

`mask` will now contain *exactly* 4 "set" bits - one in each of its 4 "sections". Even *if* `2**(hash % f)` is the same for each iteration, it'll still end up in different places, since we shift the mask.

This will not have the same false positive rate as a proper hashing function, but at least it'll be predictable. But it will be slightly worse overall.

In essence, what we have are four Bloom filters, each set to \$k = 1\$ and \$m = f\$. So (if my math is correct, which is *not* something to rely on) our false positive rate should be the regular rate for one such filter, but to the power of 4. Or, in mathematical terms:

$$(1 - (1 - \frac{1}{f})^{n})^{k}$$

(I *think* that's correct but I may be completely wrong)

Comment: I DID consider using ruby's `Hash` but since it seeds a new value for each process I decided that would not be good. Other implementations I have seen use CRC32. Hashes use the `division method` to fit into an array so that is what I used. I have the documentation for those variables at the top. I added link to another implementation that I was using to understand the functionality.

Comment: @gitarchie Whoops - sorry about missing the comments at the top. Must've scrolled around, and not scrolled all the way back. As for using `#hash`, yours is a fair point. At least with a single hashing method, it's easy to swap out the logic there (especially since it's flawed)

Comment: Why do you think digest is flawed, I asked a question here and implemented based on answer and reference implementation I found. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/260459/bloomfilter-in-ruby-should-have-k-hash-functions/260477#260477

Comment: @gitarchie Perhaps my understanding is flawed, but that question pertains reusing hashing functions (w/ seeding); not the _output_ of said hashing function. My point is that if the hash of an item sets fewer than _k_ bits, then you increase the risk of false positives. If e.g. _k_ is 5, but the item hash you're using only sets a single bit, then the question of whether the filter includes the item hinges one just 1 bit - not five. Thus, the false positive rate will increase. The rate will be somewhere between the rate for _k_ = 1 and _k_ = 5

Comment: oh ok, I don't know the answer to that, But Google's bloom filter selects optimal parameters based on expected false positive rate. I don't understand all of it, it is in cpp, Maybe you will https://code.google.com/p/bloom/

Comment: @gitarchie I've added a big chunk at the end of my answer, which you might find interesting. It was just something I did for fun, but this is _absolutely_ not my area of expertise, so take it with a grain of salt :)